# Unexpected usage of belowdisplayshortskip in amsart

Tags: formatting, amsart, vertical-spacing

In the following MWE, the lengths `abovedisplayshortskip` and `belowdisplayshortskip` are redefined to very large values to make them obvious.

My expectation is that those lengths would be used independently from each other according to whether the text would overlap the equation. Instead, what seems to happen is that a short preceding text sets the next equation into a ‘short mode’ where the short lengths are used at both boundaries.

**Question:**
Is it possible to patch `amsart` to use the short lengths according to my expectation?

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{8pt plus 8pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{8pt plus 8pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{40pt plus 8pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{40pt plus 8pt}

This is preceded by a long line of text.
It should use a long skip.
\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
    2 + 1 = 3
\end{equation}
I expect very large spaces above and below the word “but” that is between the equations.
Instead, I got very large spaces around the second equation.\\
abovedisplayskip: \the\abovedisplayskip\\
belowdisplayskip: \the\belowdisplayskip\\
abovedisplayshortskip: \the\abovedisplayshortskip\\
belowdisplayshortskip: \the\belowdisplayshortskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line preceding the display is short (short according to the rules described in the TeXbook), TeX will use `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowshortskip` before and after the display respectively. TeX *doesn't* look at the line following a display, which is treated as a paragraph of its own, preceded by `\postdisplaypenalty`.

Once the end of the display is processed, the skip and the penalty are inserted and TeX resumes typesetting.

You can somewhat cure the problem with `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` (the latter requires `mathtools`), but not automatically, I'm afraid. However something like

```
text
\begin{gather}
a=b\\
\shortintertext{but}
c=d
\end{gather}
text
```

will use `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` no matter what's the length of the line preceding the interrupted display.

Comment: What I understood from your post is that the limitation does not come from `amsart` from TeX itself. Grrr. Anyway, would it be possible to patch `\end{equation}` to include `\setlength\belowdisplayskip{ -0pt}` according to the length of the next line?

Comment: @Hector I don't think you can without absorbing the whole following paragraph and doing a trial typesetting, which opens a can of worms.